# How to get the JsonConverterAttribute to use the same NamingStrategy as the JsonConvert.Deserialize function

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonconverter, naming-strategy

I have the following class to serialize

```cs
class Container
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PropertyConverter))]
    public PropertyBase SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Which is serialized with

```cs
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
    {
        NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
    }
}:

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    new Container
    {
        SomeProperty = new PropertyImplementationA
        {
            PropertyA = "some string value"
        }
    }, settings);
```

but when I deserialize with

```cs
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container>(settings);
```

The converter is not used.

On investigation, if I remove the sname case naming strategy it all works so it appears that Newtonsoft is registering the the converter to the property name with a different naming strategy when using the `JsonConverterAttibute`.

#### Constraints

As a workaround one can register the converters with the serializer settings I won't always know the converters to be used when the settings are created, that isn't a feasable option for this case.

As another workaround one can decorate the properties with `[JsonProperty("property_base")]` explicitly but this also isn't feasable as we would need to decorate properties all over the codebase.

This works as expected if one doesn't specify the SnameCaseNamingStrategy however this strategy is what the codebase already uses and can't be changed.

#### Question

How does one get the `JsonConverterAttribute` to use the same naming strategy as the `JsonSerializerSettings` passed to the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` function?

#### You can run a working example in .Net Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iSqOpC)

Comment: We need a json and a code example for a test, othervise nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a working example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iSqOpC

Answer (score 2):

It seems that ContractResolver gives  a  priority to a JsonConverter. I
think maybe it is a good idea otherwise it would be hard to predict a result. If you move a contract resolver into a JsonConverter or  add the property names explicitly everyting is ok

```
class Container
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PropertyConverter))]
    [JsonProperty("some_property")]
    public PropertyBase SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
class PropertyImplementationA : PropertyBase
{
    override public string Type => nameof(PropertyImplementationA);
    [JsonProperty("property_a")]
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
}
```

Everything is working fine when I added contract resolver settings inside of the json converter. In this case you don't need JsonProperty attributes. I also made the converter much more simple

```
override public PropertyBase? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, PropertyBase? existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
            {
                NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
            }
        };
var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
return (PropertyBase)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jObject.ToString(), 
Type.GetType((string)jObject["type"]),settings);
}
```

and classes could be much more simple too

```
class PropertyImplementationA : PropertyBase
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
}

abstract class PropertyBase
{
    public string Type
    {
        get { return this.GetType().Name; }
    }
}
```

and even more simple , you can use SerializeTypeNameHandling option of Newtonsoft.Json https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes the issue is that the properties aren't being registered with the correct casing so I'd like to know how to do so without having to hardcode each property name. Surely there must be some way to achieve this as Newtonsoft just needs to register the converter to the snake cased property name. 

This all works in ASP.NET if one does `services.AddNewtonsoftJson(o => o.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver { NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy() });`

Comment: @Jay I think this question is out of the scope. You have to email it to James Newton-King. I  just  can offer you a workaround.

Comment: @Jay And see my update. I moved settings inside of the converter. Now you don't neeed JsonProperty attributes

Comment: Thanks @Serge. Based on your responses I think my question was a bit too open ended. It took a while to find better wording so thanks for bearing through that.